# Python anonymous pipe set timeout

Tags: python, linux, ipc, pipe

I have a feeling its not possible; but is there a way to set a read timeout on an anonymous pipe in Python / C on Linux?

Are there better options than setting and trapping a SIGALRM?

```
>>> import os
>>> output, input = os.pipe()
>>> outputfd = os.fdopen(output, 'r')
>>> dir(outputfd)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspace', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines', 'xreadlines']
>>>
```

(no `settimeout()` method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try using the `select` module, which does allow you to provide a timeout.  Add the file object to the select set, and then examine the return object to see if it's changed:

```
r, w, x = select.select([output], [], [], timeout)
```

Then examine r to see if the object is readable.  This can be extended to as many objects you want to monitor.  If the object is in r, then do a read: `output.read()`.

Also, you may wish to use `os.read`, rather than fdopen, as it will not be subject to the whims of Python's file buffering.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something simple, but `select` will tell me when there was activity (something i was planning on using)- but will not help me figure out how much data is in the pipe.  So a `read()` without the right size will just wait until EOF.  I was hoping with a way to create a timeout, I could not block forever if I read more bytes than in the pipe.  Anyone know how the `multiprocess` and `subprocess` modules manage it without digging into the code? (a likely helpful adventure)

Comment: read() will return the current amount of data in the pipe.  It will not block until the buffer is full, unless you call it again.

Comment: Oh.  You should probably use os.read() on the pipe, rather than doing an fdopen on it.  Treating it as a file object makes you subject to the whims of Pythons buffering.

Comment: unfortunately, it won't return everything in the buffer. I've tried and the help page says as much `read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.
    
    If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
    Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
    may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.
`

Comment: ah! the `os.read()` helps! Thanks (create an answer to that effect so I can select it- even though it doesn't answer the question asked :p )

Comment: @tMC If you don't know the maximum size of the data that might be sent, you'll have to use select in a loop until it returns EOF (that is, zero bytes).  To be extra safe, you should set the pipe in non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct setting, but you could use `select` on the file descriptor to wait for input.  It's a built-in module, and supports all file descriptors on Unix, but only sockets on OpenVMS and Windows (from the pydoc page on `select`).